# Escape spetial charachters when transform Koa request body to String

Tags: json, string, hmac, koa, stringify

I need to have my koa request body as a String, I tried with JSON.stringify(ctx.request.body)

It worked as expected however with some spetical charachters for example like this one '\ /' (remove space in the middle) it's being escaped to '/'.

In my case I am verifying an HMAC signature so I need the body as it is as a String.

Replacing the following '/' with '\ /' after JSON.stringify(ctx.request.body) is not a perfect solution as I will need to replace all escaped charachters ...

Thank you